# Dealing with NAs in a loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I have a loop that is checking to see if the each Zipcode[ i ] equals Zipcode[ j ] where there are some NAs for entries of Zipcode[ j ]. I just need the dummy variable for Urban to take a 1 if Zipcode[ j ] is a match for any of the Zipcodes in list urbanZips.

I've tried

```
for(i in 1:end){
    for(j in 1:end_1){
        if(urbanZips[i]==data_individual$Zipcode[j]) data_individual$Urban=1
    }
}
```

And I've also tried

```
for(i in 1:end){
    for(j in 1:end_1){
        if(urbanZips[i]==data_individual$Zipcode[j]){
            data_individual$Urban[j]=1
        } else {
            data_individual$Urban[j]=0
        }
    }
}
```

And for both I'm getting `Error in if (urbanZips[i] == data_individual$Zipcode[j]) data_individual$Urban = 1: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

I know there are NAs but there are also probably some missing values as well. There are close to a million observations.

Comment: Use `is.na` to check for `NA`.  Probably you don't need a loop here

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

We could use `outer` here

```
m1 <- outer(urbanZips, data_individual$Zipcode, FUN = `==`)
+(colSums(m1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was able to figure it out myself, leaving this here in case others come across something like this.

`library(data.table)`

`setDT(data_individual)`

`data_individual <- data_individual[, Urban := as.numeric(Zipcode %in% urbanZips)]`